# Ballotine of Foie Gras - chop or not?

Tags: duck, liver, pate

I am in the process of making a ballotine of foie gras.

The liver has been cleaned of veins and is currently in 2 large pieces. It has been marinading in Sauternes / salt / pepper for the last 24 hours. Should I chop the Foie Gras, or leave it in larger pieces when I make my ballotines? To make the ballotines I will wrap in cling film, pierce air pockets etc. and then simmer in water at around 80C for 10 mins before refrigerating overnight for consumption tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at five recipes, none of them called for the foie gras to be chopped.

You have already cleaned the liver, and have a different method chosen to form the ballotines, but I really liked these instructional photos from [The Renaissance Girl Cooks](http://renaissancegirlcooks.blogspot.com/2012/11/philip-howards-foie-gras-ballotine.html) describing the method from The Squire (a restaurant with two Michelin stars), and thought that later users might find them helpful.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]